# I want to create hive external table for Unix file directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

I want to create hive external table for Unix file directory, not for HDFS. Mean I want to give external path of a Unix directory so that my hive external table could point a unix file. Is it possible in hive?.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Did you try anything so far?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: No it is not possible. You have to copy the files to HDFS directory